# Beamer ToC subsection numbering in rectangles

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I am using `rectangles` innertheme in beamer. I want to print the subsection numbers in alphabets in ToC. For example, with the following snippet:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
%%%\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered] %doesn't work

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{ToC}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Test 1}
\subsection{Test 11}
\begin{frame}
page 1
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test 12}
\begin{frame}
page 2
\end{frame}


\section{Test 2}
\subsection{Test 21}
\begin{frame}
page 3
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

What I wanted is the rectangle before **Test 11** will contain **a**, ... Like:

[image]

Any help?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine the subsection template to include the subsection number:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}

\newcounter{mynumber}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{
    \leavevmode\leftskip=5ex%
  \llap{%
    \usebeamerfont*{section number projected}%
    \usebeamercolor[bg]{section number projected}%
    \vrule width2.25ex height1.85ex depth.4ex%
    \hskip-2.25ex%
    \setcounter{mynumber}{\inserttocsubsectionnumber}%
    \hbox to2.25ex{\hfil\color{fg}\alph{mynumber}\hfil}}%
  \kern1.25ex\inserttocsubsection\par}
\makeatother 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{ToC}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Test 1}
\subsection{Test 11}
\begin{frame}
page 1
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test 12}
\begin{frame}
page 2
\end{frame}


\section{Test 2}
\subsection{Test 21}
\begin{frame}
page 3
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]